# Is it possible to decrypt an encrypted column in CSV loaded to BQ table with the same Cloud KMS key?

Tags: sql, encryption, google-bigquery, google-cloud-kms

I create a symmetric key in Cloud KMS and I used Python to encrypt some of the column in my CSV data (as a string by decoding the ciphertext).

Then, I load this CSV file to a BQ table. I have an idea to decrypt the column using KMS via SQL and I found this document about column-level encryption from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-key-encrypt#use_cases)

But I am not sure that it only possible for the data that encrypted with the provided SQL function or not (seems like it)

There are some field that I don't actually know whether to put something

```
DECLARE KMS_RESOURCE_NAME STRING;
SET KMS_RESOURCE_NAME ="gcp-kms://projects/<project>locations/<location/keyRings/<keyring>/cryptoKeys/<key>"
;
select id
, AEAD.DECRYPT_STRING(KEYS.KEYSET_CHAIN(
    KMS_RESOURCE_NAME,
    first_level_keyset,
    name
    additional_authenticated_data)
FROM 
mydataset.mytable
```

What actually I should put for `first_level_keyset`  and `additional_authenticated_data` if I just need only to decrypt a pre-encrypted column that I did previously in CSV?

Edit:

The reason I have to encrypt data beforehand is because I store these data in my data lake in GCS first which I want it to be encrypted and no PII data in both GCS and BQ